# laravel5.8:GET 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, get, file-not-found

I am using laravel 5.8 and laravel-medialibrary:^7.0.0.

I want to upload my image, and retrieve in profile edit page.
But it doesn't work.

In my console, I got an error `GET 'my image file' 404 (Not Found)`.

This is my code. I used this code after `php artisan storage:link`

**show.blade.php**(my profile edit view page)

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$channel->image) }}" alt="">
```

also, I tried

```
<img src="{{ $channel->image() }}" alt="">
```

**ChannelController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, Channel $channel)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $channel->clearMediaCollection('images');
            $channel->addMediaFromRequest('image')
            ->toMediaCollection('images');
        }

        $channel->update([
            'name'=> $request->name,
            'description'=> $request->description
        ]);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

**Channel.php**

```
public function registerMediaConversions(?Media $media = null)
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
            ->performOnCollections('images')
            ->width(100)
            ->height(100);
    }
```

This is my table.

media table
[image: media table]
channel table
[image: channel table]

filesystems.php

```
 'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Please replace `<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$channel->image) }}" alt="">` with `<img src="{{ storage_path($channel->image) }}" alt="">`.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work...

Comment: Show your `image path` in database ?

Comment: Hi, I added. The database pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `storage_path` Laravel function to get the fully qualified path of `storage` folder.
Refer to the [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-storage-path)

eg.
`$filename = storage_path('/imageFolder/photo.jpg');`

Comment: Where do I need to put this code ? Thank you for answering.

Comment: What is your app/config/filesystems.php ?
What is your media path in laravel-medialibrary? https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary

You can also see information about how to retrieve mediya from media lib from 
https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/basic-usage/retrieving-media/

Comment: I put media path, but it seems there is no problem.